# Reading Excel Files from Linux without Accents

Tags: java, excel, character-encoding

My problem is the following one: I have an excel file where certain cells have values with accents. While running my ADF App Local on windows, I'm able to read these cell's values and generate a pdf. But when I deploy to a weblogic server under linux, I see that the values extracted from that cells have accents as my pdf gets filled with those values... What would be the problem ?. They told me that it was the charset. Does anyone have a clue ?.

Comment: You are trying to read a Windows Excel file on Linux?

Comment: thankx for the answer... yeas... the same excel file I use it when I deploy to test... but as when Iam running local I am under windows, thats why I think I don't get those accents... I don't remember the java library... but I'll post the code tomorrow...

Answer (score 0):

The code I added to solve this is:

```
            WorkbookSettings workbookSettings = new WorkbookSettings();
        workbookSettings.setEncoding("Cp1252");
        Workbook w = Workbook.getWorkbook(this.getFileDestinatarios().getInputStream(),workbookSettings);
```

Cheers